android emulator issue - windows 11
form few days the android emulator is not opening in my system. Using wireless debugging for running my react native app but i want to test my app simultaneously in different android devices and screens sizes. How to resolve this issue?

Tried checking and updating SDK, clearing Gradle caches and restarting system. Also tried with different SDK versions and devices (Tablets, WearOS) emulators, but every time i created emulator and opened it, immediately it says the process terminated

Please kill the emulator process from the task manager (you can find it starts with qemu-) and start your emulator again.


Try to create a new Android Emulator with API 33.
Also, ensure that your environment variables are added correctly.
You can also create a resizable Android emulator. This allows you to test your app on different screen sizes using a single emulator.


Low disk space can cause emulators to terminate unexpectedly. Ensure you have enough free space on the drive where the emulator is stored.

After creating the emulator, Wipe Data of emulator and then start it will work.


i tried this already as well
